# Will I Be In Trouble for Adding the "NullReferenceException" Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

One of my reasons for posting  was to use it to close most such questions as a duplicate.

But I've also been adding the [nullreferenceexception](/questions/tagged/nullreferenceexception) tag to  all of these questions.

In the past, I was asked to discuss such things with the Community. So - discussing.

Comment: There's already a `nullpointerexception` tag. I'm not sure if we should just create a synonym, or if the differences are less subtle than I'm assuming.  Either way, retagging shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. They're different class names in different languages, not just basically the same concept with two names.  I say carry on with the new tag.

Comment: I'll try to avoid getting any badges in the [tag:nullreferenceexception] tag.

Comment: You already have the honorable distinction of being the [Top Asker](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/nullreferenceexception/topusers).  ;)

Comment: Just an excess of caution: I was threatened with summary suspension once for adding a tag to existing questions: someone _else_ got a badge for that one, and I was _still_ threatened with suspension.

Comment: Usually a null reference exception is an indicator of a highly localized question.  Additionally, it doesn't add much value, and is easily picked up by search.  What benefit does using the tag have?  Will people *want* to categorize questions by this?  I wager no.

Comment: I don't personally have any problem with this tag; I've seen far worse ones.  I can see people sifting through the questions in this tag to learn more about null reference exceptions, although I can't imagine anyone following it.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the questions are actually *about* `NullReferenceException`, I would think this is fine.

I would resist adding it to questions where the code might just happen to *result* in such an exception (I don't think you're doing this, just for the record).